# R package is not loading in 15.10

Tags: 14.04, shared-library

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10 (64 bit). Now, I tried to run R package from the command line, it gives the error message as

> /usr/local/lib/R/bin/exec/R: error while loading shared libraries: libicuuc.so.52: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

Any idea how to rectify this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The missing file `libicuuc.so.52` is part of the package `libicuuc52` in **Vivid**.
In Wily there is the newer version `libicuuc55`.

You have at least two options. If the first option doesn't work, use the second - but not both at the same time. **;)**

- Download and install the Vivid package

  ```
  cd
  wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu52_52.1-8ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
  sudo dpkg -i libicu52_52.1-8ubuntu0.2
  ```

**OR**

- Install the version for Wily and create a symbolic link

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libicu55
  sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.52
  ```